# How to dynamically load a component with settings in CakePHP 2?

Tags: cakephp, constructor

I understand that we can pass settings for a component when we define the component at the start of a controller. Example from the CakePHP 2.0 Cookbook

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array('controller'),
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        )
    ),
    'Cookie' => array('name' => 'CookieMonster')
);
```

But I usually load components on the fly like so (also from the Cookbook)

```
$this->OneTimer = $this->Components->load('OneTimer');
```

While using the second method (loading a component on the fly), how can I pass settings to it so that I can use them in the constructor to correctly setup the component based on the settings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 minutes after asking the question I looked at the load function in the library and found that settings is the second argument for the function.

```
public function load($component, $settings = array())
```

So I just need to supply the settings as the second parameter when I load components on the fly.